# service account roles to deploy google cloud function

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-functions, service-accounts

I'm trying to use `gcloud beta functions deploy` from CI using a service account, but get an error:

> (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) ResponseError: status=[403], 
>   code=[Forbidden], message=[The caller does not have permission]

I can't find any roles in the IAM web console that look appropriate.  Which one do I use?

Comment: - Could you expand CI acronym?

- Please run the command with --log-http to see which call is failing.

- Please run `gcloud auth list` to check what account gcloud authenticates as.

Comment: @BasketWeaver CI = Continuous Integration (Jenkins/Bamboo/Bitbucket pipeleines etc).  I'm using a gcloud service account (bitbucket-authorization@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com).  It's pretty clear what's happening on the network - I'm trying to execute "gcloud.beta.functions.deploy" and the response is 403 because the service account does not have the correct priveleges.  Adding "Owner" and "Editor" as QuestionAndAnswer suggests would likely fix the problem, but I was hoping for a more specific Role.

Comment: It seems there aren't any roles with narrower permissions that would allow deploying a function. And there are no permission for doing just that so it seems you can't even create your own role for that :(

Comment: According to https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1beta2 the scope required is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" ...that still doesn't map to anything in the Roles though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To deploy function user should have role `roles/cloudfunctions.developer`

I found this by changing role in UI. I couldn't find any official google documentation. This role is also mentioned in this article https://medium.com/google-cloud/triggering-cloud-functions-deployments-97691f9b5416

Answer (score 5):

Check your current config : `gcloud config list`

View result and check `project =` is exact same as your target project's **PROJECT_ID**.

You can list your projects : `gcloud config set project`

**IMPORTANT**

`Project =` is not set NAME. MUST SET **PROJECT_ID**.

Comment: Thank you @takashi! This is yet another misleading error message from google

Answer (score 5):

This is the minimum role required for my Service Account (not the default Cloud Functions service account) to successfully deploy a Cloud Function using CI.

> ```
> Cloud Functions Developer
> Service Account User
> ```

From the docs

> In order to assign a user the Cloud Functions Developer role (roles/cloudfunctions.developer) or a custom role that can deploy functions, you must also assign the user the IAM Service Account User role (roles/iam.serviceAccountUser) on the Cloud Functions Runtime service account.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles

One thing which i don't understand is the mention of Runtime Service Account. You don't have to assign the Service Account User role to Runtime Service Account, rather it should be to your SA which you are using to deploy.(Not sure whether I understand the doc correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You can always begin from this two options. At least they must work.

[image]

And make sure that you set up all required environment variables to make Default Application Credentials work.

Comment: I was hoping for "Hi, I'm from google,we've just added 'Cloud Functions' Roles", but for now "Editor" works...

Comment: @NicholasAlbion that seems under expectation :)

Answer (score 0):

It pretty much explains how to add the correct roles here: [service account roles to deploy google cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44587490/service-account-roles-to-deploy-google-cloud-function)

TLDR:

1. `roles/cloudfunctions.developer`
2. `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).