# Deploy gen2 Google Cloud Functions with GitHub Actions?

Tags: python, typescript, google-cloud-functions, github-actions

I was able to easily deploy to GitHub Actions for 1st generation Google Cloud Functions, but now with 2nd generation, I get authentication errors.

How can I set up a GitHub workflow to deploy my function when I merge or push to my `main` branch?

Here is the workflow I was using before

```yaml
      - id: "deploy"
        uses: "google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions@v0"
        with:
          name: "<cloud-function-name>"
          runtime: "python310"
          region: "us-east1"
          entry_point: "<function-in-main-file>"
          timeout: 540
          service_account_email: PROJECT@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
          ingress_settings: ALLOW_ALL
          max_instances: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got this working from a comment on [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloud-functions/issues/304#issuecomment-1476629207). Their comment is for a Node function. The code I offer below is for Python, but it's the same for all of them.

You'll need a service account json key and the yaml that uses it - and that's it!

**Service Account**

1. Create a [service account](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/iam-admin/serviceaccounts?supportedpurview=project) in the project via the GCP console

   - Give it `Cloud Functions Developer` and `Service Account User` permission ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145227/1759443))
2. Click into the service account -> Keys -> Add Key -> Create JSON key
3. Copy the JSON
4. Now go to your [GitHub](https://github.com/dashboard) repo settings -> "Secrets and variables" (Sidebar) -> Actions
5. Click "New repository secret"

   - Name: `GCP_SA_DEPLOY_KEY` (or whatever you want, it goes in the yaml below)
   - Secret: Paste the JSON service account key

**GitHub Action**

Create `.github/workflows/deploy-python-src.yml` in your repo (name it whatever you want).

Update the deploy command in the code below (ask ChatGPT if you need help figuring it out). Make sure it works by running it locally before testing the action.

```yaml
name: Deploy Cloud Functions
run-name:  ${{ github.actor }} is deploying all cloud functions
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: ls
      - id: 'auth'
        name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
        with:
          credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_SA_DEPLOY_KEY }}'
      - name: 'Set up Cloud SDK'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1'
        with:
          version: '>= 363.0.0'
      - name: 'Use gcloud CLI'
        run: 'gcloud info'
      - name: 'Deploy to gen2 cloud function'
        run:  |
          gcloud functions deploy <cloud-function-name> \
          --gen2 \
          --region=us-east1 \
          --runtime=python310 \
          --source=<source-folder-in-repo> \
          --entry-point=<function-in-main-file> \
          --trigger-topic=<topic-if-pub-sub>
```

**⚠️Notes⚠️**

- If you get errors related to Cloud Run, you can see the specific issue in the Cloud Run GCP console.
- The [package that handles the auth](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth) advises against Service Accounts and provides another option (Workload Identity Federation). Read their README for specifics to know if it's secure in your scenario.